# C# How can I break ParentId chain in App Insights?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

I have a houskeeping function that runs on a timer. It selects work to do from the DB and then posts off multiple messages for that work to be done.

When I look at the TimeLine for those work items in App Insights they are all grouped together, because they were all initially called from my housekeeping function.

I'd like the timeline of each to start with the processing of the job itself, so I can see their timelines independently.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: What kind of application are we talking about? A web app? Where is the timer created, a background worker?

Comment: @PeterBons It is an Azure Function app, with a [TimerTrigger] attribute.

Comment: And your issue is that all work being done during an execution is grouped together? Can you post the outline of the code or sketch the process and give an example of the desired breakup?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions offers built-in integration with Azure Application Insights to monitor functions. Timeline view mainly displays event types containing timestamp and duration as a base properties (but not as custom properties) such as Request, Dependency (displayed over time) or critical events with timestamp such as an exception (displayed as a point in time).

The way you can solve this is by disabling the automated logging from application insights, and instead do it all manually. According to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-data) :

> In C# and JavaScript, you can use an Application Insights SDK to write custom telemetry data.

If you need to set custom telemetry, you need to add app insights java SDK to your function. Check this [Track custom operations with Application Insights .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking) document for more information.

Comment: I don't want to disable it and change the rest of my app. I just want to clear the current tracking ID.